# cloning Windows XP using transfer box

Tags: windows-xp, bootable-media, disk-cloning, transfer

I have 2 hard drives which are both 1TB SADA/64MB cache WD10EZEX. Neither of which are in a computer. The 1st hard drive has Windows XP installed on it with a ton of source code and a compiler. This drive is bootable if installed in a computer.

The 2nd hard drive is identical to the first however it is totally empty. No OS either.

I want to clone drive 1 to drive 2 so that I could swap out drive 1 with drive 2 and expect drive 2 to boot as well.

Can this be done in a reliable fashion? 
I have purchased a usb transfer box that will handle IDE and SATA drives. What software do you recommend to clone hard drive 1 to hard drive 2.

Comment: Why is this on hold? Despite mentioning the drive type, no product recommendation is requested, and service or learning material isn't as well. In my opinion, this qualifies as a normal superuser question, where users might want to recommend dd on linux or something similar to accomplish this task.

Comment: @DavidPostill Reason for closing??

Comment: @LukeLR "What software do you recommend"

Comment: @Biswapriyo "What software do you recommend"